# Java JNI Field does not exist

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to connect my c++ dll to my java application(Running a test version now) I am trying to get the x, y, and z values from a class inside an object(polygon) and cant quite figure out why i am getting this error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: position
>       at jnidemojava.Main.sortPolygon(Native Method)

I don't have a lot of experience with JNI i actually got only about 5 hours trying to figure things out. Please help me. What the dll should do is get the x, y and z values from the vector class within my polygon object and get the distance from that to the camera's vector3f C++ code :

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_jnidemojava_Main_sortPolygon
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject, jobjectArray polygon, jobject camPos) {
    // Get the class
    jobject inCArray = env->GetObjectArrayElement(polygon, 0);
    if (NULL == inCArray) return NULL;
    jsize length = env->GetArrayLength(polygon);

    // Step 2: Perform its intended operations
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int k = i; k < length; k++) {
            jobject obji = env->GetObjectArrayElement(polygon, i);
            jclass polyClass = env->GetObjectClass(obji);
            if (polyClass == NULL)
                printf("Poly is null");
            jclass vec3Class = env->GetObjectClass(camPos);
            if (vec3Class == NULL)
                printf("Poly is null");
            jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(polyClass, "position", "Ljnidemojava/Vector3f;");
            jobject vec3 = env->GetObjectField(vec3Class, fid);
            jobject objk = env->GetObjectArrayElement(polygon, k);
            if (obji > objk) {
                env->SetObjectArrayElement(polygon, i, objk);
                env->SetObjectArrayElement(polygon, k, obji);
            }
        }
    }
    return polygon;
}
```

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package jnidemojava;

import jnidemojava.Main.Vector3f;

/**


*
 * @author Soultaker
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    private static native int add(int a, int b);
    private static native int[] sort(int[] num);
    private static native int sum(int[] array);
    private static native void printArr(int[] array);
    private static native polygon[] sortPolygon(polygon[] p, Vector3f campos);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.load("C:\\Users\\Soultaker\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\JNIDemoCdl\\x64\\Release\\JNIDemoCdl.dll");
        int p = add(10, 22);
        System.out.println("10 + 22 = " + p);

        int[] s = new int[]{
           10, 5, 12, 13, 33 
        };
        System.out.println("Sorted array : ");
        s = sort(s);
        printArr(s);
        System.out.println("Ohh *** sorting polygons");
        polygon[] h = sortPolygon(new polygon[]{new polygon(10, 20, 20),
            new polygon(20, 10, 50)
        }, new Vector3f(100, 10, 111)
    );
    }

    public static class Vector3f {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        public Vector3f(float x, float y, float z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
    }

}

class polygon{
   Vector3f position = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0);

    public polygon(int x, int y, int z){
        position.x = x;
        position.y = y;
        position.z = z;
    }
}
```

Comment: All the other code works(Other native methods), is just the sortPolygon one that would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(polyClass, "position", "Ljnidemojava/Vector3f;");
>   jobject vec3 = env->GetObjectField(vec3Class, fid);`

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. The `position` field exists in `polygon` *instances*; it's not a static member of any class, certainly not the `Vector3f` class.

If you want to get the `position` from a `polygon` you should pass an instance of `polygon` (e.g. `obji`) as the first argument to `GetObjectField`.

Also, since `Vector3f` is an inner class of `Main`, its signature would be `"Ljnidemojava/Main$Vector3f;"`

Once you have read the `position` you get get its `x`, `y` and `z` fields in the following manner:

```
jfieldID xid = env->GetFieldID(vec3Class, "x", "F");
jfloat x = env->GetFloatField(vec3, xid);
// and similarly for y and z
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i relized that in EJP's comment, i moved the polygon and vector classes out of the main class to their own classes in the jnidemojava package, i tried to use a full path and it did not find the position in the polygon class as you can see :
`
jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(polyClass, "position", "LC:\\Users\\Soultaker\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JNIDemoJava\\src\\jnidemojava\\polygon;");
jobject vec3 = env->GetObjectField(vec3Class, fid);`

Comment: Well, like I said in my answer, it doesn't make any sense to pass `vec3Class` to `GetObjectField`. You should pass a `jobject` that references an instance of `polygon`.

Comment: And how do i get the x, y, and z values from vector3f(position)? Thats basically all i want, because if i can get that i can calculate the distance to camPos and then sort the polygons with the distance

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(polyClass, "position", "Ljnidemojava/Vector3f;");
```

but

```
import jnidemojava.Main.Vector3f;
```

Obviously the JNI signature of the field is wrong. Should be something like `"Ljnidemojava/Main/Vector3f;"`, but don't rely on me, and don't ever try to write them yourself. Use the output of `javap -s`. It is never wrong.